# Does a symmetric expression in $x,y$ take optimum value only if $x=y$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a symmetric expression in $x,y$.Suppose $f$ has a maximum or minimum.Then does it occur at a point where $x=y$?Can it happen that $f$ is optimum although $x\neq y$?
I have used this result many times this thing but I want to know rigorously if the result is always true.Can someone help me?I think due to symmetry this should always happen.

Comment: Surely $x=y$ does not always imply the function is maximal or minimal

Comment: @idlemathematician I have edited the title,please see.

Comment: Consider $\cos(x)+\cos(y)$

Comment: @idlemathematician so what?

Comment: The pairs $(2n\pi, 2m\pi)$ are all maxima for $m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$, so we have a maximum at $(0, 2\pi)$ for example

Comment: See [When does symmetry in an optimization problem imply that all variables are equal at optimality?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/58721)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we can conclude in general is that the set of points where $f$ takes its maximum (or minimum) value is symmetric under the transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ i.e symmetric under reflection in the line $y=x$ (as long as the domain of $f$ is large enough). Think about the maximum points of $f(x,y) = (y-x)^2$ in a square centred on the origin, for example.

Answer (score 4):

If "$f(x,y)$ is a symmetric expression in $x,y$" means that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y$, the answer is no.

Take $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)\neq (1,0), (0,1)$, and set $f((1,0))=f((0,1))=1$.

This yields a counterexample.

If this counterexample is unsatisfactory to you, here is another one.

Take the square $C$ of length $2$ centered at the origin O, and for all $M=(x,y)\in C$, let $f(x,y)$ be the distance $OM$. Certainly, $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y$ such that $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $C$, but the minimum is obtained for the points $(1,0), (-1,0),(0,1), (0,-1)$.

Comment: then under what additional conditions can we claim the result to be true?

Comment: @idlemathematician what additional condtions on $f$ is needed to make it true?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar [This other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58721/when-does-symmetry-in-an-optimization-problem-imply-that-all-variables-are-equal) seems to have some answers to that.